# Lambda function within a class attribute

Tags: python, class, lambda, syntax-error

Task: Get `price` in `self.priceTable` with given `reqId` as input.

This code of a class method does work as expected:

```
priceTable = self.priceTable
price = next(filter(lambda priceTable: priceTable['reqId'] == reqId, priceTable), None)
```

This code gives an invalid syntax error:

```
price = next(filter(lambda self.priceTable: self.priceTable['reqId'] == reqId, self.priceTable), None)
```

What's wrong with that? Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: I can't get the code you say works to run without an exception (`TypeError: string indices must be integers`)—so it's unclear what you're asking. Offhand it sounds like you don't know what a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression does or how to use them. Please [edit] and improve your question so the code in it at least reproduces the problem (or in this case a version of it that works as you claim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda` has to be followed by an ordinary variable, it's just like the parameters to a function. You only need to provide `self.priceTable` in the argument to `filter`:

```
price = next(filter(lambda p: p['reqId'] == reqId, self.priceTable), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.priceTable` is not a valid parameter name. Parameters should be just names, and you can pass `self.priceTable` to the lambda function as an argument:

```
price = next(filter(lambda priceTable: priceTable['reqId'] == reqId, self.priceTable), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear because there too little code in it to really understand what you're trying to accomplish—so sorry if this doesn't apply. However, from what currently is in it, I don't think you need to be using a `lambda` or the built-in `filter` function at all to accomplish the task.

Instead you could just use the existing dictionary method [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) as shown below to do it:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.priceTable = kwargs.copy()

    def get_price(self, reqId):
        return self.priceTable.get(reqId, None)

inst = Class(id1=1.23, id2=2.34, id3=3.56)
print(inst.get_price('id2'))  # -> 2.34
print(inst.get_price('id9'))  # -> None
```

Comment: Thanks, you understood my question correctly. However priceTable is a list of dictionaries with multiple keys so I think Barmar's solution is the perfect way to go.